# Dynamic database connection in pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I am new to Pentaho report designer.
I am working on generating huge number of reports using a sample database locally available. once we move to the production i ll have to change all the report database connection credentials individually . Is there a way to configure the database connection in one place and use the same in all reports?

Comment: You should use JNDI connection not JDBC connection

Comment: can you please tell me more about it ? any forum link i can follow and do the configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setting/ write JNDI connection and then use this connection in your each report.

1. During report development, you can write JNDI connection in your PC HOME location like "C:\Users\User\ .pentaho\simple-jndi\default.properties"
2. After deploy report in pentaho server, you require to create same JNDI connection from your pentaho server with same JNDI name. Pentaho server JNDI file location is like "D:\pentaho\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\simple-jndi\jdbc.properties"

**Sample JNDI connection information for Oracle:-**

```
oracleAbc/type=javax.sql.DataSource
oracleAbc/driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
oracleAbc/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:chaucerdb
oracleAbc/user=scott
oracleAbc/password=abc$123
```

After that you can use this ConnectionName as your JNDI connection in report.

Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: i am using Oracle. can i do the configuration in pentaho/pentahoserver/pentahosolutions/system/simplejndi/jdbc  property file

Comment: Yes . You can create JNDI connection for almost any DB. And you know before doing this we must keep OracleDriver in proper location :)

Comment: mydb/type=javax.sql.DataSource
mydb/driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
mydb/url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost)(PORT=myport)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservicename)))
mydb/user=myuser
mydb/password=mypassword.......................................... i have added this in jdbc property file... should i configure the same in repository.xml ?

Comment: I am using pentaho CE . I haven't required to add this in 'repository.xml'. So i think its not require. I already include Oracle sample JNDI connection information in my answer.

Comment: i am receiving Invalid data source:'oracleAbc' error

Comment: Error found from which tools? Is it from report designer preview or from pentaho BA Server? Error seems indicate you were not write JNDI information in correct location.

Comment: error found in report designer while testing jndi connection.  i have included  JNDI connection information in jdbc propertyfile

Comment: During development report in report designer, you need to write JNDI information in location like "C:\Users\User\.pentaho\simple-jndi\default.properties"  file. Did you do this?    Help "https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0H0/Specify_Data_Connections_for_BA_Design_Tools/010"

Comment: Thanks a ton Sakil.. its working now :) i had missed a line in default.properties.

Comment: hi Sakil.. when i try to publish the report  its throwing an error saying jndi not found.. any where else i have to define the database connection ?

Comment: Yes, after publish , you need to follow my 2nd option. Write exact SAME JNDI information on location "D:\pentaho\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\simple-jndi\jdbc.properties". And run BA server again.